# Calculate phase angle in Optical flow

Tags: matlab, opencv, opticalflow

i want to an understanding about phase angle of optical flow. if I know about particular point `Vx` and `Vy` ( velocity), Then how can I calculate `phase angle`(radian) using the above parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a point, with optical flow value of Vx,Vy, the angle can be calculated as follows:

```
angle = atan2(Vy, Vx);
```